# Foursquare API's explore endpoint returns different result when I request

Tags: python, foursquare

I'm trying to get all of the venues near a location with provided latitude and longitude. I required more than 50 venues if there is that much, however I get less results than I expected. Here is my code:

```
RADIUS = 200
LIMIT = 200
offset = 1
VERSION = '20200603'
latitude = 40.7127281
longitude = -74.0060152

url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}&ll={},{}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(
    CLIENT_ID, 
    CLIENT_SECRET, 
    VERSION, 
    latitude, 
    longitude, 
    RADIUS, 
    LIMIT
    )

result = requests.get(url).json()
```

I get 20 venues of different type categories. This is less than the amount of venues I expected, so I tried to do the same explore request from Foursquare API endpoint example:
https://foursquare.com/developers/explore#req=venues%2Fexplore%3Fnear%3DNYC

This time I get 42 venues results. I checked for the parameters of the endpoint, the limit and radius that might influence the result, but the result is still the same.

Does anyone ever done same request have any advice?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please show us `latitude, longitude` value

Comment: I'd add  the parameters, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

e.g. https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?ll=35.6662026,139.7312591&client_id=XXXX&client_secret=XXXX&v=20200603&radius=200&limit=200 returned 42 results.

Maybe There aren't a lot of results near you. Try something more general, reset your filters, or expand `radius`.

Comment: The latitude and longitude is located in New York city, and I want to retrieve venues from any type within the radius 200 meters. It shouldn't be only 20 returns, and I do get 42 venues when trying on the Foursquare explore endpoint example.